# MapBox URL not working

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Below is a HTML and javascript I'm using for loading a map in my browser.
I createda map at Mabbox.org. So the leaflet URL of the map is :

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/johnmichel/ciobach7h0084b3nf482gfvvr/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoiam9obm1pY2hlbCIsImEiOiJjaW9iOW1vbHUwMGEzdnJseWNranhiMHpxIn0.leVOjMBazNl6v4h9MT7Glw
```

Now I put this URL in a Javascript function called init() ; I followed this http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html. But when I load the HTML, no maps appears. Could you help me here ?

**Javascript**

```
function init(){

var map = L.map('map');

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/johnmichel/ciobach7h0084b3nf482gfvvr/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoiam9obm1pY2hlbCIsImEiOiJjaW9iOW1vbHUwMGEzdnJseWNranhiMHpxIn0.leVOjMBazNl6v4h9MT7Glw', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

  map = L.map('map').setView([46.2, 2], 5);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="monstyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="leaflet/leaflet.css">
    <script src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="MonFichierJS.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

<div id="map"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body, #map {
    height: 500px;
width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: For testing purposes, try giving your `#map` a height in pixels instead of %

Comment: @chrki As expected it has resized the div. I chose 500px for both height and width. The map still isn't showing (I only see the zooming buttons + and - ). I've edited my OP to change the CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the Javascript. Below is a correct JS code

```
function init(){

var map = L.map('map').setView([46.2, 2], 5);

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/johnmichel/ciobach7h0084b3nf482gfvvr/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoiam9obm1pY2hlbCIsImEiOiJjaW9iOW1vbHUwMGEzdnJseWNranhiMHpxIn0.leVOjMBazNl6v4h9MT7Glw', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

}
```